# How to get checkbox submitted data in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a form to get the books that the user most interested on the form contain tabs for each category and each tab contain number of checkboxes so the user can check the name of the books that he like.the problem here that I can't get the value of the checkbox which is contain the books name.

**View**

```
<? echo $this->Form->create('Book', array('id'=>'booksform', 
                                          'url'=>array('action' => 'your_books')));  ?>

<div id="tabs-1">
    <? echo $this->Form-> input('books',array('type' => 'select',
                                              'multiple' => 'checkbox',
                                              'name' => 'books',
                                              'options' => $biographies,
                                              'label'=>false));?>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <? echo $this->Form-> input('books',array('type' => 'select',
                                              'multiple' => 'checkbox',
                                              'name' => 'books',
                                              'options' => $history,
                                              'label'=>false));?> 
</div>
<? echo $this->Form->end(); ?>

<?  echo $this->Form->submit(__('Submit'),array('class'=>'btn btn-primary','div'=>false)); ?>
```

**Controller**
I have tried this

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $books = $this->request->data( 'books');
}
```

and this :

```
$books = $this->request->data['Book']['books'];
```

Comment: and what is in $this->request->data after selecting some books?

Comment: I got  nothing 
( ' ' )

Comment: even after submitting your form?

Comment: Two things: You should not have 2 inputs with the same name in one form (`books` and `books`), **and** you should call the `submit` method **before** the `end` method, because in your case  your are submitting nothing (and that's probably what causes your problem).

Answer (score 0):

You form should look like this :

```
<? echo $this->Form->create('Book', array('id'=>'booksform', 
                                          'url'=>array('action' => 'your_books')));  ?>
<div id="tabs-1">
  <? 
  $biographies = array('1'=>'a','2'=>'b');
  echo $this->Form-> input('books',array('type' => 'select',
                                              'multiple' => 'checkbox',
                                              'name' => 'books',
                                              'options' => $biographies,
                                              'label'=>false));?>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
  <? $history = array('3'=>'c','4'=>'d'); 
  echo $this->Form-> input('books',array('type' => 'select',
                                              'multiple' => 'checkbox',
                                              'name' => 'books',
                                              'options' => $history,
                                              'label'=>false));?> 
</div>
<? 
echo $this->Form->submit(__('Submit'),array('class'=>'btn btn-primary','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Here Passed 'multiple' parameter in field name so its value storage as array format.

Sp after submit, by Below code returns all comma separated checked checkbox id

```
 <?php echo implode($this->request->data['books'],','); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to have these two div's  and  ?

Because I think your HTML should be flexible enough to accommodate all the chekboxes under a single div. If you try that, I assure you that your problem will be resolved.